# Using IEnumerable<T> to parse XML

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using Linq to parse a simple XML file into a var (ienumerable), I'm stuggling at getting the data out into the seperate string variables. I'm using a simple foreach loop (there is only one result) but it's not not outputting anything. Here's the code i'm using;

```
XElement xmlResults = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
var timerresult = from timers in xmlResults.Descendants("e2simplexmlresult")
                  select new GetResult
                  {
                    e2state = timers.Element("e2state").Value,
                    e2statetext = timers.Element("e2statetext").Value
                  };

foreach (var item in timerresult)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(item.e2state);
  Debug.WriteLine(item.e2statetext);

}
```

Is there something i'm not doing correctly, is this the best way to achieve the desired result?

EDIT: Here's the XML;

```
<e2simplexmlresult>
    <e2state>False</e2state>
    <e2statetext>Conflicting Timer(s) detected!  / A Place in the Sun: Home or Away / Goals On Sunday</e2statetext> 
</e2simplexmlresult>
```

Comment: That would be fine if there were any `e2simplexmlresult` elements, but we don't know what your XML looks like.

Comment: Please post an example of the XML you are trying to parse.

Comment: What is the input XML you are using? Perhaps your timers collection is empty? What happens when you set a breakpoint and look at the results. Might be helpful to introduce more intermediate variables when debugging.

Comment: I'll add the XML above. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change XElement to XDocument, or still use the XElement in combination with DescendantsAndSelf(...). By using XElement, the "e2simplexmlresult" tag is not part of your result , thus has no descendants. Using DescendantsAndSelf() or using XDocument overcomes this issue.

Comment: that's sorted, thanks for your help. I went from using Descendants to DescendantsAndSelf and all is working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your sample xml, I wrote the following piece of code(in LinqPad) and it runs fine :

```
XElement xml = XElement.Parse(@"<e2simplexmlresult>
            <e2state>False</e2state>
            <e2statetext>Conflicting Timer(s) detected!  / A Place in the Sun: Home or Away / Goals On Sunday</e2statetext> 
        </e2simplexmlresult>");

GetTest test = new GetTest()
       {
           e2state = xml.Elements().Where(x => x.Name == "e2state").First().Value,
           e2statetext = xml.Elements().Where(x => x.Name == "e2statetext").First().Value,
       };

Console.WriteLine(test.e2state);
Console.WriteLine(test.e2statetext);
```

Try and see of the logic given here, can be of some help to you or not.

Comment: never heard of linqpad before, but it looks pretty interesting! thanks